# Problem in inner query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT ReviewMain.LoanID AS [Loan ID], ReviewMain.Asofdate AS [As of Date],  
  (SELECT CreditRating FROM  tblReviewScalars AS Review 
   WHERE (Review.AsOfDate = (SELECT Max(AsOfDate) FROM tblReviewScalars 
                             WHERE AsOfDate<#4/19/2011#))
     AND (Review.LoanID=ReviewMain.LoanID)
     AND (Review.Asofdate=ReviewMain.Asofdate)) 
  AS [CreditRatingAt prior AsOfDate], 
FROM tblReportVectors AS ReportMain INNER JOIN
     tblReviewScalars AS ReviewMain ON (ReportMain.LoanID = ReviewMain.LoanID) 
                                 AND (ReportMain.AsOfDate = ReviewMain.AsOfDate)
WHERE (ReviewMain.Asofdate= DateValue(FunAsofdate()))
GROUP BY ReviewMain.LoanID, ReviewMain.Asofdate;
```

in above query i have outer query & inner query i get answer for both but when i write `(Review.LoanID=ReviewMain.LoanID) AND (Review.Asofdate=ReviewMain.Asofdate)` this in inner query i get blank value but actul answer is for creditrating is CCC-. is any soloution on inner query .

Comment: Your query is so badly formatted that I don't even think it's possible to understand it. I tried and all I could get was a query that was not syntactically correct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This subquery:

```
(SELECT Max(AsOfDate) FROM tblReviewScalars 
 WHERE AsOfDate<#4/19/2011#)
```

Is returning the max AsOfDate prior to 4/19/2011 for ***ALL*** loans, as opposed to the max AsOfDate for the loan in the current row.  You need to change the above subquery to this:

```
(SELECT Max(AsOfDate) FROM tblReviewScalars AS MaxPrior
 WHERE MaxPrior.AsOfDate<#4/19/2011# 
   AND MaxPrior.LoanID=ReviewMain.LoanID)
```

Also, you need to get rid of the trailing comma on the line `AS [CreditRatingAt prior AsOfDate],` so that you have syntactically correct SQL.